# Python how to revert move operation into a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know if and how it's possible to revert a move operation or deconstruct the file that was created. I wrote a script that should've moved all nested jpg files into a folder but instead wrote it to a file. This is due to an error in the target path, I missed the slash at the end to denote it was folder.

This is the code that created the mistake:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from sys import argv
from os import walk, path
from fnmatch import fnmatch
from shutil import move

rootdir = argv[1]

for root, dirs, files in walk(rootdir):
    for filename in files:
        if fnmatch(filename, '*.jpg'):
            print(f'moving {filename} to {rootdir}')
            origin = path.join(root, filename)
            target = path.join(rootdir, 'Pictures')
            move(origin, target)
print('done.')
```

Comment: This seems to move *all* files to the *same* location, meaning all but the last are overwritten. Is that correct? Note that this would mean there isn't anything to "move back" but the last file – the rest is gone. You might be able to recover something from trash, but that may depend on OS and settings.

Comment: Sorry, but this a great lesson on why to either use version control for files or experiment on backups files not real ones. As mister said, the files are probably overwritten (not multiple jpegs in a single file).